# Java Inheritance - sibling's overriding method issues

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, overriding

I have 4 classes, 1 parent class and 2 inheriting child(siblings), and one interface (service callback, that does something every set of time (e.g every 5 seconds), by the way this is done from Android development.

Ill post the 3 classes excluding the interface to reduce some codes

**The Parent Class, BaseActivity.java**

```
 public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements BackgroundServiceCallback{

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         BaseActivity.this.startBackgroundService();
     }

     @Override
     public void onBackgroundServiceCallback() {
         // no concrete implementation (will be implemented in child_a)
     }

     public void startBackgroundService() {
         // configure and start the service here
     }
}
```

**An inheriting Child, ChildActivity_A.java**

```
  public class ChildActivity_A extends BaseActivity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // some activity configurations here.
     }

     @Override
     public void onBackgroundServiceCallback() {
         // concrete implementation goes here, and will work
     }
 }
```

as you can see above(what ever the background service is doing) the Child_A's concrete method(implementation will work every time a callback happens

now this is where it becomes tricky(on my perspective) 
here is the third class

**An inheriting child ChildActivity_B.java**

```
  public class ChildActivity_B extends BaseActivity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // some activity configurations here.

         // if I call super.startBackgroundService() or this.startBackgroundService
         // ChildActivity_A's implementation is not being called
     }
 }
```

If i call the startBackgroundService from ChildActivity_B the concrete implementation on ChildActivity_A is not being called

I've been doing java programs way before android development, taking things for granted, I think i missed some things about inheritance that makes me confuse in this situation.

I just need some enlightenment on why does it happen, (By the way I resolved the real problem by setting a static flag in a custom Application class to start a service or not in an activity)

Comment: I missed one test here, I tried to call **super.startBackgroundService()** on **ChildActivity_A**, and the overriden method works. now this is what I understand.. is there anything called _"implicit method overriding?"_ thats why when I call **super.startBackgroundService()** on **ChildActivity_B**, **ChildActivity_A's** implementation of  **onBackgroundServiceCallback()** is **NOT** being called because there is an ** "IMPLICIT"** or hidden overriding in ChildActivity_B?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `"BaseActivity.this.startBackgroundService()"` is actually start background service, which is available in `BaseActivity.java`. In your `ChildActivity_B` you are calling it by `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. So it will only call it's super method, which is available in it's super class `BaseActivity.java`, not `ChildActivity_A`. `ChildActivity_B` actually doesn't know anything about `ChildActivity_A`.

Comment: "ChildActivity_B actually doesn't know anything about ChildActivity_A" - you gave me a hint

Comment: Great if it helped you in any way.

Comment: wait I added a comment above, I really want to justify my understanding. is it there an implicit overriding?

Comment: @zabdiel There is NO implicit method overriding. Overriding is always _explicit_. Moreover: One class just inherits the non-private methods from its parent classes. There is no overriding nor inheritation relationship between sibling classes.